# Unable to write date to file

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, c++-chrono

I came across an idea where I wanted to log what my program is doing with date and time. So I wrote a small function, and upon compilation no error, and no runtime error except that it doesn't open log.txt and it won't even display the date.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

void log(const char*& text)
{
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open("log.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    fs << ctime(&now) << text << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char* log("Testin codenz stuff");
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `std::fstream::in` and `std::fstream::app` at the same time.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating as to your reason?

Comment: @KiloKing Fixing your primary error regarding the pointer reference [It works just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c702c4117bc0943d).

Comment: @KiloKing Don't disable warnings. They are there for a reason, and, unless you're doing really borderline things with the language, you should listen to what they say

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
 const char* log("Testin codenz stuff");
```

is defining a local variable named `log` of type `const char *` with the value "Testin codenz stuff" .. it's not a function call. Just do this:

```
 log("Testin codenz stuff");
```

Comment: Thank you, although technically the line `log("Testin codenz stuff");` isn't correct, need to pass in a `const char*` argument.

Comment: Get rid of the `&` in the function signature.